# Exclude Activity from recents and history

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

Actually I have a direct issue with android custom tabs.
But nevertheless I will generalize my question. Let's assume that I have `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. `ActivityA` - is an external one, so that we launch it from an Intent :

```
Intent intent = customTabsIntent.intent;
        intent.setData(requestUri);
        intent.putExtra(CustomTabsIntent.EXTRA_TITLE_VISIBILITY_STATE, CustomTabsIntent.NO_TITLE);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

From here we see that `ActivityA` - is actually a custom tab activity. When things get done I launch `ActivityB`. I want `ActivityA` dissaper from task history, I can achieve this by aplying flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`  to my intent. But this approach is causing problems, because when user switches to recents,or goes to other app - `ActivityA` disappears forever. Of course - that's how flag no history works. But I want a different flow, I want `ActivityA` disappear only when `ActivityB` was launched. Any ideas how to achieve this?

**P.S. I need to finish `ActivityA`, which gets launched via intent, I don't have access to its code and I don't have the ability to call `finish()`.**

Comment: You can call `finish()` after `startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: what do you mean by **"I don't have access to its code"** and why can't you call finish()??

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay as I mentioned - ActivityA is custom tabs activity, that's android activity, not mine.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a contradiction in your question. Can you tell the intent code that you have written above is used to open the ActivityA or ActivityB?? and for my knowledge can you also tell what is android's custom tabs activity?

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Sure, NP! https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay some caller, doesn't matter who - launches ActivityA by sending intent(that I described), after ActivityA has finished its work it fires an intent that launches ActivityB. Makes sense to you or still not really clear?

Comment: How and when is ActivityB launched?

Comment: @DavidWasser From ActivityA, some kind of inner logic, in my case - custom Tab is parsing url and building from it an intent, which actually launches ActivityB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this by using the NO_HISTORY flag since `ActivityA` is doing the launching and you have no control over it.

However, you should be able to achieve your goal (not being able to go from `ActivityB` back to `ActivityA` by overriding the BACK button in `ActivityB` and having it go back to whatever is underneath `ActivityA` in the task stack.

Assuming that `ActivityC` is the one that starts `ActivityA`, you could do something like this in `ActivityB`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Direct user back to ActivityC
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
    // Add flags to ensure that we reuse the existing instance of
    //  ActivityC and that we clear any other activities above ActivityC
    //  from the stack.
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I like your solution. It solves my problems. Quite simple workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `finish()`   method to clear any activity. so before starting another `activity` finish that.

```
 Intent intent = customTabsIntent.intent;
            intent.setData(requestUri);
            intent.putExtra(CustomTabsIntent.EXTRA_TITLE_VISIBILITY_STATE, CustomTabsIntent.NO_TITLE);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        finish();     //add this to clear that activity
```

Comment: I need to finish ActivityA, which is launched by intent.